# taylor series for finding cosine

Tags: c, taylor-series

For an assignment I need to write a c program that finds the cosine of an entered angle using the taylor series expansion, which goes up the 50th term (meaning the final term is x^100/100!). So far I've been trying to use a for loop and I also tried a while loop but I keep getting incorrect answers. I already have working power and factorial functions, and I already have the value of the angle in terms of radians, I just don't understand how to format the loop so that I get a logical answer.

This is the part where I ask the user for an angle, convert the angle to radians, and call the function:

```
printf("Enter an angle measure in degrees to find the cosine value:\n");
scanf("%lf",&angle);
angle = angle * (M_PI/180);
result = myCos(angle);`
```

And this is the function:

```
long double myCos(double x)
{
  long double result = 0;
  double term = 0;
  int k = 0;

  for(k = 2;k <= 100;k += 2)
  {
    term = power(x,k)/factorial(k);
  }

  result = 1 - term;
  return(result);
}
```

Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You just told a story: you wrote some code, it was wrong, you got the wrong answer. This is a question-and-answer site. There's no question to answer here.  "I don't understand" is a fact, not a question; there's nothing we can do except say "go ask your professor for help".

Comment: Note that `term = power(x,k)/factorial(k)` discards the previous value of `term` and replaces it with the next term of the series. You probably want to accumulate terms.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to calculate `x^k` or `k!` each pass through the loop. Initialize the quotient outside the loop, then multiply by `x/k` (or `x^2/k(k-1)`, if you only want the odd terms), to update the quotient for each iteration.